# Count using Sumproduct with OR Condition is not Returning Required Result

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, ms-office

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Rate | Weight | Count | Item | Category |
| 20$ | 65 |  | Caps | Sold |
|  | 80 | 400 | Caps | Sold |
|  |  | 500 | Caps | Sold |
|  | 90 | 991 | Caps | Sold |

This is my Data in sheet, (actually there is a lot, its just a sample)

Now i want to see, How many empty cells with pending rates are there where Category and Item is same, but Count or Weight cell is not empty and surely there are 3 cells in Rate Column which are not filled yet.

Formula i am trying in F1 is

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(E2:E6="Sold"),--(D2:D6="Caps"),--(A2:A6=""),--(C2:C6<>"")+--(B2:B6<>""))
```

and its returning me the Ans **4** which is wrong, Ans must be **3**
Please guide me how to solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
=SUM((A2:A5="")*(((B2:B5<>"")+(C2:C5<>""))>0)*(D2:D5="Caps")*(E2:E5="Sold"))
```

Where `(((B2:B5<>"")+(C2:C5<>""))>0)` means we want to check if either column B **or** column C has any value. Also, `SUMPRODUCT()` is a remnant from previous versions of Excel to cancel auto-implicit-intersection. In ms365 this is no longer needed due to dynamic arrays, hence you can just use `SUM()`.

Answer (score 0):

or may be if you are using Office 365

```
=SUMPRODUCT((E1:E5="Sold")*(D1:D5="Caps")*(A1:A5="")*(B1:B5<>""))+(@C1:C5<>"")
```

or may be

```
=COUNTIFS(E2:E5,"Sold",D2:D5,"Caps",C2:C5,"<>")
```